# Couple java questions regarding type casting and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

Hello I have a few questions regarding type casting and inheritance. I have been doing some reading and I understand the point and basics of type casting. However, I don't fully understand where I can and can't use it.

Consider this class:

```
class A{

        public A(){}            

}

A temp = new A();

temp = (Object)temp;
```

This code gives me the error "Cannot convert from type Object to type A". However, wouldn't this be converting from type A to type Object? Can you not type cast up the hierarchy?

Now my second question regards inheritance and such.

When you type:

```
Object temp = new A();
```

what is really happening? Is temp an A or is it an Object?

Comment: @fge Is it? It just makes an empty constructor

Comment: Oops, I am mistaken... But the `;` is redundant

Comment: @appman0724 it is `A`. you'll be using instance variables and methods of `A`

Comment: @fge Oh yes the ; is not necessary thanks

Comment: @mangusta Why does it want me to cast it to type A before using A's instance methods?

Comment: This however --> `A = (Object)temp;` will not compile; you have not declared `A`. Maybe it was `A a` or something?

Comment: `A` is a class name. how can you assign something to class name?

Comment: @fge oops another mistype I meant temp not A

Comment: The code was supposed to be temp = (Object)temp;

Comment: @appman0724 you're supposed to use typecast `(Object)` to assign some variable to another variable of class `Object`. but you assign it to variable of class `A`

Comment: @mangusta so I can't cast from type A to Object? Is it ok to cast from type Object to type A

Comment: @appman0724 it is meaningless in your case. It is used when for example you have `Object temp1` and `A temp2`, and you want to cast `temp2` to `temp1`, you use `temp1 = (Object)temp2;`

Comment: @mangusta oh I see. The issue is not in the casting from type A to Object, its in the fact that Im assigning this casted object back to an A type?

Comment: @appman0724 yes, that's the point of typecast. it's meaningless to cast to class other than specified in parentheses `()`

Answer (score 0):

Here the excerpt from [JLS 8.1.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html):

> If the class declaration for any other
>   class has no extends clause, then the
>   class has the class `Object` as its
>   implicit direct superclass.

Of course, `Object` itself is a bit special ([JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html)):

> Each class except `Object` is an
>   extension of (that is, a subclass of)
>   a single existing class (§8.1.3) and
>   may implement interfaces (§8.1.4).

Every Class is a descendant of `Object`.

In your case, you are trying store an object of `A` into a Class object called `A`. This isn't going to work. You need to do:

`Object testObject = (Object)temp;`

This will store the `Object` into `testObject`, which has the type `Object` that you casted to.

Here it is [working on ideone](http://ideone.com/bSzc0b).

Answer (score 0):

```
A a = (Object)temp;
```

> "Cannot convert from type Object to type A". However, wouldn't this be converting from type A to type Object? Can you not type cast up the hierarchy?

You are correct that

```
(Object)temp;
```

is converting `temp`, which is an `A` to an `Object`. However, that's not what the compiler is complaining about. Now that you have, effectively,

```
A a = anObjectNOTAnA
```

(`A = ...` is invalid code. I've changed it to `A a = ...`.)

It's saying that you cannot convert an `Object` back to an `A`, unless you explicitely cast it and potentially suppress the unchecked-cast warning:

```
A a = (A)anObjectNOTAnA
```

or

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
A a = (A)anObjectNOTAnA
```

---

Regarding your other question:

```
Object temp = new A();
```

> What is really happening? Is temp an A or is it an Object?

When you cast an object of any type, it never *changes* the actual type of the underlying object. A `new A()` is always an `A`, whether its

```
A a = new A();
```

or

```
Object objButReallyA = new A();
```

or

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
A a = (A)((Object)new A());
```

If an `A` is stored in an `Object`, it's just a different "view" of the same object. In order to use the `A` specific functions, however, you must first revert it back to the `A` view:

```
 objButReallyA.getAOnlyField();  //compile error

 ((A)objButReallyA).getAOnlyField();  //Okay
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you can't assign superclass object to the subclass reference.

So you can't do:

```
temp = (Object)temp;
```

because it's the same as:

```
Object newObject = new Object();
A temp = newObject;
```

You will get the same compile error here.

Of course you can do something like that:

```
Object newObject = new Object;
A temp = new A();
newObject = temp;
```

You can do it because you can assign subclass to the superclass reference

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the last line. First you promise Java that temp is of type Object by the statement:

```
(Object) temp
```

Afterwards you try to assign an object that the compiler thinks is of type Object to a variable that should be of type A. So to conclude, the part where you cast temp to type Object is fine, the problem is when you afterwards try to assign it to a variable expecting something of type A.

For your second question, temp is an A. When creating an object with the new keyword, the type of the object will always be whatever comes right after. In your case A. Afterwards you then assign temp to a variable of type Object, but that does not change the actual type of temp. Having a variable of some type X just tells you that whatever the variable is pointing to is a subtype of X.